# Writing fraction in matrix

Tags: spacing, matrices, fractions

I am trying to write a fraction in a matrix. I am doing it using the following code:

```
\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
     \frac{1}{6} & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{5}{6} \\
     \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6}
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
```

What I get is as follows:

[image]

But what I am trying to achieve is:

[image]

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: instead of `\frac{a}{b}`, you should just write `a/b`. It's that straight-forward.

Comment: Yes!! It works. I thought complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of writing `\frac{a}{b}`, use `a/b`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1/6 & 5/6 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1/6 & 0 & 5/6 \\
    5/6 & 0 & 0 & 1/6
  \end{bmatrix}
  \qquad
  \renewcommand{\frac}[2]{#1/#2}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{6} & \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{5}{6} \\
    \frac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6}
  \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

In the second example above I've redefined the way `\frac` works to print it the way you want. Since the redefinition is done inside a display math *group*, it's normal function will be reset after `\]`.

Of course, one could also redefine the way `\frac` works globally, but that would not make sense.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `nicefrac` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

    \[
    \begin{bmatrix}
     \nicefrac{1}{6} & \nicefrac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & \nicefrac{1}{6} & 0 & \nicefrac{5}{6} \\
     \nicefrac{5}{6} & 0 & 0 & \nicefrac{1}{6}
  \end{bmatrix}
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]